# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to push item in my list .

This is model to need add in list .

```
export interface OfflineLessonList {

    id: number;
    title: string;
    courseId: number;
    coursetitle: string;
    published: boolean;
    payType: PayTypes;
    parentId: number;
    displayOrder: number;
    childes: OfflineChildLessonList[];

}

export interface OfflineChildLessonList {

    id: number;
    title: string;
    courseId: number;
    coursetitle: string;
    published: boolean;
    payType: PayTypes;
    parentId: number;
    displayOrder: number;

}
```

i try to use this code :

```
treeToFlat(lessons: OfflineLessonList[]): OfflineLessonList[] {

    let data = new Array<OfflineLessonList>();

    lessons.forEach(parent => {

        let model = {} as OfflineLessonList;
        model.parentId = parent.parentId;
        model.payType = parent.payType;
        model.published = parent.published;
        model.title = parent.title;
        model.courseId = parent.courseId;
        model.coursetitle = parent.coursetitle;
        model.displayOrder = parent.displayOrder;

        if (parent.parentId === null) {

            data.push(model);

        } else {

            lessons.forEach(element => {
                let i = 0;
                if (parent.parentId === element.id) {
                    let find = data.find(x => x.id === parent.parentId);
                    find.childes = [];
                    find.childes.push(model);
                }
                i++;
            });

        }
    });

    console.log('in tree', data);

    // lessons.forEach(parent => {
    //  data.push(parent);
    //  parent['children'].forEach(lesson => {
    //      data.push(lesson);
    //      console.log(lesson);

    //  });
    // });
    return data;
}
```

but it show me this Error :

> Cannot set property 'childes' of undefined

**Whats the problem ? how can i solve this ??**
?

Comment: could you host a demo on stackblitz?

Comment: This line here "let find = data.find(x => x.id === parent.parentId);" may return undefined if no element match. So check for undefined before pushing child to it

Comment: @Mridul this is all of my code

Comment: @R.K.Saini it return value

Comment: @kianoushdortaj The error message "Cannot set property 'childes' of undefined" simply state that you are trying to set childes property on an undefined object. As you loop through an array it may possible some lesson may have null as parent_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this code:

```js
lessons.forEach(element => {
  let i = 0;
    if (parent.parentId === element.id) {
      let find = data.find(x => x.id === parent.parentId);
      find.childes = [];
      find.childes.push(model);
    }
    i++;
});
```

There are cases where `let find = data.find(x => x.id === parent.parentId);` will return undefined if it is unable to find a record. So you need to handle that case.

Consider checking the value exists before attempting to push:

```js
lessons.forEach(element => {
  let i = 0;
    if (parent.parentId === element.id) {
      let find = data.find(x => x.id === parent.parentId);
      if (find) {
        find.childes = [];
        find.childes.push(model);
      }

    }
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let find = data.find(x => x.id === parent.parentId);
```

find value is undefined here

> Return value of find method
>
> The value of the first element in the array that satisfies the
>   provided testing function. Otherwise, undefined is returned.

you are trying to set property for undefined value, hence it gives error

Answer (score 1):

Add additional check

```
let find = data.find(x => x.id === parent.parentId);
if (find) {
  find.childes = [];
  find.childes.push(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
let find = data.find(x => x.id === parent.parentId);

if(find){
    find.childes = [];
    find.childes.push(model);
}
```